# Why does the configured dropdown box not appear within the jqgrid cell?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

QUESTION:  Why does the dropdown box not appear within the cell, below  (i.e., column "value2").  The cell is blank.  (the other cells are properly displaying correct values)

To my "untrained" eye it seems that I am using the the correct technique, as shown in the jqgrid demo.
--But, unfortunately, no dropdown box appears in the column.
(i.e., please see column "value2", in my jqgrid configuration, below).

What part of the jqgrid table configuration is preventing the dropdown widget from appearing in the cell?

Note: I modeled the row definition after that shown in the "Input Types" demo....
i.e.,

```
        {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true,edittype:"select",editoptions:{value:"FE:FedEx;IN:InTime;TN:TNT;AR:ARAMEX"}},
```

Thank you for any help!!

s

---

## UPDATE:

Here is how I'm handling checkbox (below).  I was hoping to handle a dropdown similarly...(snippet follows)

```
    $("#xyzgrid").jqGrid({
    .
    .
    .
    colModel: [
    {   name: 'valw', 
        label: 'valw', 
        index: 'valw', 
        width: 50, 
        formatter: 'checkbox', 
        editable:true, 
        edittype:"checkbox", 
        editoptions: {value: 'true:false'}, 
        formatoptions: {disabled:false}}, 
    ],
    .
    .
    .     
    });

    $("#xyzgrid > tbody > tr > td > input[type=checkbox]")
    {
        $(this).change( function(e){
            var t = $(e.target);                       
            var row = t.closest("tbody").children().index(t.closest("tr"));     //...row index...
            var rowids = $('#xyzgrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');                    //a zero-based array containing rowids of visible rows...
            var rowid = rowids[row-1];
            var rowdata = $("#xyzgrid").getRowData(rowid);
            $("#xyzgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', rowid, rowdata); 
        });
    };

    $("#submit").click(function() 
    {
        var gridData1 = $("#xyzgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
        var gridData1String = JSON.stringify(gridData1);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: suburl1,                            
            data: "gridData1String=" + gridData1String,
            dataType: "text",
            async: true,
            success: function() {
                alert("Submitted");
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("xhr status=" + xhr.status);
                alert("thrownError=" + thrownError);
            }
        });                        
    });
```

---

## Here is my JQGrid configuration:

```
            var geturl1 = 'data/getGridData1';

            $("#abcgrid").jqGrid({        
                url: geturl1,
                mtype: 'POST',                    
                datatype: "json",
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "data", 
                    page: "pageNo", 
                    total: "pages",
                    records: "rows",                        
                    repeatitems: false,
                    cell: "",
                    id: "value0"
                },                    
                colNames: ['value0', 'value1', 'value2'],
                colModel: [
                    {name: 'value0',    index: 'value0',    width: 100},
                    {name: 'value1',    index: 'value1',    width: 100},
                    {
                        name: 'value2',    
                        index: 'value2',    
                        width: 100,      
                        editable: true,  
                        edittype:"select",  
                        editoptions: {value:"AAA:AAA;BBB:BBB;CCC:CCC"}
                    }
                ],
                rowNum:5,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'value1',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption:"abctest grid...",
                rownumbers: true,
                loadonce: true                
            });
```

## UPDATE#2:

Here is the most recent "working" rendition of my jqgrid.   The only problem it has occurs when the user clicks the "submit" button.   Apparently, the last dropdown edit made by the user, leaves the row in "edit" mode... Therefore, this value is not include in the post to the server...

***Below, is the "working" code (thanks to AJ and Oleg)...***

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>abctest</title>


            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

            <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
            <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.json-2.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        

            <script type="text/javascript">
                /* <![CDATA[ */
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    var grid = $("#abcgrid").jqGrid({
                        url: 'data/getGridData1',
                        mtype: 'POST',
                        datatype: "json",
                        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
                        editurl: 'clientArray',
                        cellEdit: true,
                        jsonReader: {
                            root: "data",
                            page: "pageNo",
                            total: "pages",
                            records: "rows",
                            repeatitems: false,
                            cell: "",
                            id: "value0"
                        },
                        colNames: ['value0', 'value1', 'value2'],
                        colModel: [
                            {
                                name: 'value0',
                                index: 'value0',
                                width: 100
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'value1',
                                index: 'value1',
                                width: 100
                            },
                            {
                                name: 'value2',
                                index: 'value2',
                                width: 100,
                                stype: 'select',
                                formatter: 'select',
                                editable: true,
                                edittype: "select",
                                editoptions: {value: "AAA:AAA;BBB:BBB;CCC:CCC"}
                            }
                        ],
                        rowNum: 5,
                        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                        pager: '#pager',
                        sortname: 'value1',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        caption: "abctest grid...",
                        rownumbers: true,
                        loadonce: true
                    });

                    $("#submit").click(function()
                    {
                        var gridData1 = $("#abcgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
                        var gridData1String = JSON.stringify(gridData1);

                        alert("gridData1String=" + gridData1String);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'data/postGridData1',
                            data: "gridData1String=" + gridData1String,
                            dataType: "text",
                            async: true,
                            success: function() {
                                reloadgrid($("#abcgrid"));
                                alert("Submitted");
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                alert("xhr status=" + xhr.status);
                                alert("thrownError=" + thrownError);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

                function reloadgrid(grid)
                {
                    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {loadonce: false, datatype: 'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid', [{page: 1}]);
                    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {loadonce: true});
                    return false;
                }

                /* ]]> */

            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1">
                <div>
                    <div>                    
                        <input type="submit" id="submit"  value="Submit Grid Edits" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <table id="abcgrid"></table>
                        <div id="pager" ></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Which editing mode you use? The code which you posted don't contains editing of grid. You configured that *during editing* the cells from the column `'value1'` should be displayed as `<select>`, but it will be only after the editing will be started.

Comment: Hi Oleg - I added an update to show a sample of how I'm handling a checkbox.   I wanted to handle a dropdown similarly - if possible.   Thx  s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oleg is right.  I created a [short fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8YEJ/) using most of your code (except it loads data locally), set the editing mode, and it works fine.  You might want to work backward from a version that loads locally to a version that loads JSON, but you're not going to get any normal behavior unless you set [cellsubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing) or [editurl](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) values at the very least.

Code below:

```
<table id="theGrid"></table>
<div id="theGridPager" style="text-align: center"></div>

$("#theGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    pager: $("#theGridPager"),
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'value1',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    cellEdit: true,
    caption: 'the grid',
    colNames: ['value0', 'value1', 'value2'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'value0', index: 'value0', width: 100 }, 
        { name: 'value1', index: 'value1', width: 100 }, 
        { 
            name: 'value2', 
            index: 'value2', 
            width: 100, 
            editable: true, 
            edittype: 'select', 
            editoptions: { value: "AAA:AAA;BBB:BBB;CCC:CCC" }
        }
    ]
});

var gridData = [
    { value0: 'value0 - 1', value1: '1', value2: 'AAA'}, 
    { value0: 'value0 - 2', value1: '2', value2: 'BBB'}, 
    { value0: 'value0 - 3', value1: '3', value2: 'CCC'}
];
for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++)
{
    $("#theGrid").jqGrid('addRowData', gridData[i].value0, gridData[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  AJ.   I'll take a look at your code.   --BTW, is there any quick answer as to why "cellsubmit", "celledit", "editurl" are not (apparently) required for my checkbox example?   I.e., The checkbox renders fine and I'm NOT currently using these params with the checkbox example.  However, the dropdown box would not render at all.  Thx again!  :-)

Comment: Also, AJ - How can I get the initial cell (dropdown) value to display in the cell when the grid initially loads? For me, when the grid loads the first time, the "dropdown" cells appear blank. -- I discovered that the "dropdown" cells only display their value AFTER I click on them - and thereafter... --Thx again for your generous help!

Comment: @sairn: `formatter: 'checkbox'` is a [**formatter**](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). You wrote additional code to handle `change`. You can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) to include dropdown in the cell *during filling* of the grid, but you will have to handle `change` event also manually.

Comment: @sairn: Alternatively you can call `editRow` for every row of grid inside of `loadComplete` to start editing of all rows.

Comment: Hi Oleg. ....(1) Would you have any examples/links for: "include dropdown in the cell during filling of the grid"? ....(2) I'm not confident as to what the custom formatter should look like... I'm guessing that it would contain javascript to extract the value I need from the "select" html string that comprises the cell value)... Does that sound right? Thx again!